# cast shadow from partly transparent plane

Tags: three.js, shadow

Is there a possibility to cast shadow from a plane for which the texture plays a video with a chromakey shader ? My trial seams to answer by NO but I guess my shader is not adapted. The object is a simple PlabeBufferGeometry and the shader is :

vertexShader is :

```
varying vec2 vUv;
void main() {vUv = uv; 
vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 ); gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
}
```

fragmentShader is :

```
uniform sampler2D vidtexture;
uniform vec3 color;
varying vec2 vUv;
void main()
{   vec3 tColor = texture2D( vidtexture, vUv ).rgb;
    float a = (length(tColor - color) - 0.5) * 7.0;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(tColor, a);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `discard` keyword? If your frag shader encounters that keyword, it won't render that fragment, it's as if it didn't exist. You could use this to create shadow outlines defined by your chromakey instead of always geting a square shadow.

```glsl
void main(){
    vec3 tColor = texture2D( vidtexture, vUv ).rgb;
    float a = (length(tColor - color) - 0.5) * 7.0;

    // Do not render pixels that are less than 10% opaque
    if (a < 0.1) discard;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(tColor, a);
}
```

This is the same approach Three.js [uses for `Material.alphaTest`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/Material.alphaTest) in all their built-in materials. You can see the [GLSL source code for that command here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/alphatest_fragment.glsl.js).

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I tested it but it seems shadow calculation does'nt care to the outcome of the chromakey shader. Even if I discard all pixels, the object disappears totally but the shadow remains a full rectangle. I don't know enough about shadow calculation to understand where the problem is.

Comment: I found an exemple in three.js with transparent cloth. They attach a THREE.MeshDepthMaterial as  CustomDepthMaterial to the object ;  but in the exemple, the cloth material maps a still image. In my case, it is a video and the texture to map is actually the outcome of the chroma key shader. Don't know how to map the chromakey image at each iteration  to the customDepthMaterial ?